# bash: run multiple commands each separately with a command prompt

Tags: bash

I want to run multiple commands like they are executed one at a time on command prompt

Eg i have the following list of commands

```
ls
pwd
du -sh
```

Now i try to copy paste them and run:

```
$ ls
pwd
du -sh
file1.txt  file2.txt
/home/user/test
1M  .
```

but instead i want to get them executed separately. So that i can see their outputs like below

```
$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt
$ pwd
/home/user/test
$ du -sh
1M  .
```

So is it possible if i a have a list of commands to paste them in such a way that they can execute as if one per command prompt. Else the only option is paste one command at a time.

Generally i get a list of commands to get executed.

Comment: Not sure how you're doing it, but if I select the first list of commands you provided and middle click in my terminal prompt (XTerm), it behaves exactly as you want.

Comment: ls && pwd && du -sh  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While pasting essentially works the way you describe, it may end up looking cosmetically wrong when the input (and its local echo) shows up while the shell is still busy executing the previous command.

You could instead feed the commands to `bash -i`, which will read and execute them in turn, showing the prompt:

```
$ mypaste() { x="$(cat)"; bash -i <<< "$x"; }
$ mypaste  # Now paste some commands and hit ctrl-d
ls
pwd
whoami
^D
```

This results in:

```
you@yourdir $ ls
some files
you@yourdir $ pwd
/home/you/yourdir
you@yourdir $ whoami
you
you@yourdir $ exit
$
```

Comment: what is the syntax explanation for `x="$(cat)"`

Comment: I tried with zsh -i but its not working. Is it possible with zsh also

Comment: `x="$(cat)"` just reads stdin to the end. I don't know about `zsh`

Answer (score 1):

The answer from **that other guy** worked and I used a slightly modified version using heredoc.

I wanted to script a sequence of commands that show the prompt so I could copy/paste on different systems and show how to replicate a bug.

**simple version**

```bash
bash -i << 'EOF'
echo "command one"
echo "command two"
EOF
```

**more commands and pretty output**

```bash
bash -i << 'EOF' && echo -e '\e[1A\e[K==========================================='
unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1='command-sequence:$ ' ; clear ; echo "==========================================="
mkdir /tmp/demo-commands
echo "file contents" > /tmp/demo-commands/file
cd /tmp/demo-commands
pwd
ls
cat file
rm file
rm -r /tmp/demo-commands
EOF
```

I customize the prompt and use `echo -e '\e[1A\e[K` to replace the last line with a separator

Answer (score 0):

nano myscript.sh or your favorite editor and paste the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
pwd
du -sh
```

make it executable with `chmod +x myscript.sh` and run the script with

```
./myscript.sh
```

You can run any bash commands and see outputs

Comment: Thats one way. But i prefer to just copy paste. I am ok i have to add some extra command to show command prompt after each command

Comment: hmm maybe you can use alias

Comment: how will making a script file help.

Answer (score 0):

Try each command separated by semicolon:

`ls; pwd; du -sh;`

This will make it batch of commands. Shell will execute one by one and you don't have to paste each command separately.

Hope this helps.